# Jenkins Pipeline - Laravel Unit Testing

Tags: laravel, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I have started my laravel project, i'm trying to unit test my code and test db connectivity with jankins, this is my **Jenkinsfile** and how i configured it:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile true
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh 'php --version'
                sh 'composer install'
                sh 'composer --version'
                sh 'cp .env.example .env'
                sh 'php artisan key:generate'
            }
        }
        stage("Unit test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.image('mysql:5.7').withRun('-e "MYSQL_DATABASE=testing" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"') { c ->
                        docker.image('mysql:5').inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
                            /* Wait until mysql service is up */
                            sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb --silent; do sleep 1; done'
                        }
                        sh "./vendor/bin/phpunit"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The unit testing stage get error all the time and does not complete, why please ??

**All project configured by Docker.**

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: This error
```+ docker run -d -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testing -e DB_USERNAME=root -e DB_PASSWORD=root  mysql:5.7
docker: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
script returned exit code 127```

Comment: Can you post your docker file?

Comment: `FROM php:7.3.1-fpm-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev wget curl vim
RUN apt-get install -y git zip unzip jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libfreetype6-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring bcmath pdo pdo_mysql
WORKDIR /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your dockerfile: "apt-get install -y libltdl7". Or just add the additional "libltdl7" into your existing install statements.

I have updated the dockerfile you provided (this is untested):

```
FROM php:7.3.1-fpm-stretch 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev wget curl vim libltdl7

RUN apt-get install -y git zip unzip jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libfreetype6-dev 

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring bcmath pdo pdo_mysql 

WORKDIR /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ 

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer 

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

Comment: I already did that, but unfortunately i get new error when run tests.
When run this command => ./vendor/bin/phpunit
`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
`

Comment: Well that is not the error you shared when asked about it. This additional error you are seeing may be because you do not have your DB_HOST set correctly in your environment. You may have bigger issues related to your unit tests though. You should probably not actually be making DB calls as part of unit tests, you should look into mocking.